# Recommendation on Python stopping for a certain amount of time

Tags: python, time

I have been looking for ways to stop time in a function , I think the code I have written works just fine; but are there any alternatives or some better ways to the function I have written?
I have checked out another topic on this but I couldn't get the differences on why those would be better.

```
import time

begin_time=0
while begin_time<5:

    begin_time+=1
    time.sleep(1.0)
print("The Work is Done")
```

Comment: You tagged tkinter, is this part of a gui? Do you want the gui itself to freeze or perhaps some functionality within the gui?

Comment: If you just want to wait 5 seconds, then wait 5 seconds. No need for a while loop. You only need something more complicated if you want your wait to be anything more than just sleeping.

Comment: This is far too broad a question, and there is already plenty of information available on the subject. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Below is equivalent to your code.

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
print("The Work is Done")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but just to add some more information: time.sleep(n) is the standard way to pause for an amount of time in Python. Bear in mind that pausing really does mean pausing. Unless you are using threads, the execution of the program will completely stop until the time.sleep has finished